# Improper Integrals with an Infinite Limit of Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This is from my textbook.
[image]

the textbook says it makes no sense when $b=\infty$, I think what it want to show us is $\Delta x$ could also be $\infty$ because of $b$, but as $n$ is also  $\infty$, it still makes a little sense that $\Delta x$ could still be very small ($\frac{\infty}{\infty}$)?

Comment: Infinity is *not a number*. Don't treat it as one.

Comment: @vrugtehagel so why the textbook said it makes no sense when b is  infinity? What's being affected when  b is  infinity?

Comment: $b$ cannot be infinity. It's just not a number. You can take $\lim_{b\to\infty}$, but $b=\infty$ simply makes no sense.

Comment: @ vrugtehagel  OK, so it means that we cannot say $\infty$ minus a number like $\infty$-2, because only a number can minus a number?

Answer (score 1):

Your post does not really contain a question to answer. But like @vrugtehagel said, you should consider $\infty$ represent a concept rather than a number. For example, say $\infty := \ 'redness'$

Then saying something like $redness - 2$ simply does not mean anything. Or, $ \frac{redness}{redness} %$, for that matter.

Luckily, as you probably already learned from your calculus book, our tools allow us to compute limits involving infinity. For example, if we define

$$ \int_a^\infty {f(x)dx} = \lim_{c\to \infty} \int_a^c{f(x)dx}$$

We can easily evaluate the indefinite integral.